# Magento model delete function

Tags: magento, model

I have Model class which extends **Mage_Core_Model_Abstract**. I have a resource which extends **Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract**. Now I am deleting from controller with the following code:

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $blogpost = $this->_createModel();
    $blogpost->setId($params['id']);
    $blogpost->delete();
    echo 'Post with id ' . $params['id'] . ' is deleted';
}
```

The problem is there is no error shown when I supply **non existing** ids. What to do ? Do I have to load that id and check whether it exists or not? or should I use the **try/catch**. I used try and catch but did not give any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it does not throw an exception, the `DELETE` statement gets executed without errors eventually, it only has an affected row count of 0.

Unfortunately the row count gets lost here (`Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`):

```
/**
 * Delete the object
 *
 * @param Varien_Object $object
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
 */
public function delete(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    $this->_beforeDelete($object);
    $this->_getWriteAdapter()->delete(
        $this->getMainTable(),
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto($this->getIdFieldName() . '=?', $object->getId())
    );
    $this->_afterDelete($object);
    return $this;
}
```

because the return value of `_getWriteAdapter()->delete()` is not used anywhere

It looks like you will indeed have to load your model before deleting it, or at least check for its existence via the ressource collection.